# Is this a bug in C++ Builder or in MinGw, and MSVC?

Tags: c++, c++builder

The code below is based on the [CPP Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md), Appendix C, "Discussion: Use a factory function if you need "virtual behavior" during initialization"

The idea of the code is to use a factory function to instantiate derived classes that require a 'post constructor' to be called in the derived class.

The code I have is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class B {
protected:
    class Token {};

public:
    // constructor needs to be public so that make_shared can access it.
    // protected access level is gained by requiring a Token.
    explicit B(Token) { /* ... */ }  // create an imperfectly initialized object

    template<class T>
    static shared_ptr<T> create()    // interface for creating shared objects
    {
        auto p = make_shared<T>(typename T::Token{});
        p->post_initialize();
        return p;
    }

private: //change to protected and it compiles in C++ Builder
    void post_initialize()   // called right after construction
    { /* ... */ f(); /* ... */ } // GOOD: virtual dispatch is safe
    virtual void f() = 0;
};


class D : public B {                 // some derived class
protected:
    class Token {};

public:
    // constructor needs to be public so that make_shared can access it.
    // protected access level is gained by requiring a Token.
    explicit D(Token) : B{ B::Token{} } {}
    D() = delete;

protected:

    //Make B:create() a friend so it can access private and protected members...

    template<class T>
    friend shared_ptr<T> B::create();

private: 

    void f() override {
        std::cout << "I'm a D" << std::endl;
    };
};


int main() {

    shared_ptr<B> p = B::create<D>();    // creating a D object

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and runs using MinGW version w64 9.0 and MSVC 2022. However, C++Builder 11.5 Alexandria, Clang compiler, 32-bit and 64-bit, complains:

> error: 'post_initialize' is a private member of 'B'

But, if I change class `B`'s `private:` section to `protected:`, C++Builder compiles the code.

I expected C++Builder to compile this, as `B::create()` should be able to call a `private` function of `B`, should it not?

Or, am I wrong, and MinGW and MSVC are incorrectly able to compile this?

Comment: Looks like a bug in C++ Builder.

Comment: If you remove `Token` declaration from `D` class, then you don't even need to declare `B::create` as friend, because it will not have to access any element of `D`. And `D` constructor is still protected by `B::Token`.

Comment: Token is required to prevent the class being instantiated directly but still keep the constructor public so make_shared can access it. I had to re-read the code (which comes from the CPP Core Guidelines) a few times before grasping why this is the case. The idea is that the base class, after instantiation, always calls a post constructor in derived classes, without relying on the user to do this, which would be the case if the user could call the constructor directly...

Comment: But user will not be able to call constructor directly even if you delete `Token` from `D`, because it will need `Token` from `B` which is also `protected`.

Comment: @sklott Yes, you are right. If I change the constructor of D to explicit D(B::Token) : B{ B::Token{} } {} then I can remove the friend declaration. And C++ Builder can then compile it as well. So it seems the bug is that C++ Builder misunderstood the friend statement. If I leave the friend statement in the code, even with this improvement, C++ Builder still can't compile it...

Comment: What version of Clang does C++ Builder use? Clang 14.0.0 accepts this code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It uses v 5.0.2. They are looking to go to v14 or v15 for the next major release. It’s a long way behind the latest Clang - I don’t know why that is the case, but it probably has to do with their compiler extensions needed to support Delphi’s libraries.

Comment: @AndyB: Yeah, backward compatibility can explain a lot of motivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expected C++ Builder to compile this as B::create() should be able to call a private function of B should it not?

Yes, `post_initialize` is allowed to be used/called like `p->post_initialize()` from inside `B::create()` as both belong to the same class.

This looks like a C++ Builder bug as per your error description.

Comment: Jason, thanks for confirming I'm not going mad :-) I've raised a bug with Embarcadero...

Comment: Embarcadero reports this is a Clang issue - up to V7.1.0 the code won't compile. From V8.0 it does compile. They are currently in the process of upgrading the C++ Builder C++ Compiler to CLang V14 or V15 for a future release...

Comment: @AndyB I see. You could share a link here of that bug so that future readers can find it from here also.

Comment: I tried raising it through the Embarcadero issue reporting portal, but it was down, so I raised a support case instead. They are going to raise the error and send me the link, which I will post once I receive it.

Comment: They have added this issue in their bug tracking Jira as issue RS-115956. It’s a Clang problem, already fixed in later Clang releases and will be resolved in the next major C++ Builder release at the latest. But as @sklott showed in the comments above, this code can be changed to remove the need for the friend declaration and then the issue goes away.